# Lost focus issue when using WPF and WindowsInteropHelper

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, excel

I have a problem with hosting a WPF window inside Excel. What we want to achieve is a window similar to Excel 2013 chart icons next to the chart when chart is selected.

The normal logic is already in place, but there was an issue with click on the ribbon or switching to another window and back to Excel. Both of those scenarios resulted in our window getting hidden.

The solution to this is to set the Owner of our WPF window which is not straight forward when combining Excel and WPF windows. The solution for now was this:

```
// Getting the active window
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

// Using the WindowInteropHelper to bind WPF window to excel
var wpfWindow = new WPFWindow();
var handle = GetActiveWindow();
helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow) { Owner = handle };
wpfWindow.Show();
```

The above code works fine as long as we only stay in Excel. However the following steps produce a problem:

- show our wpfWindow from an Excel addin
- switch to another program that is currently running (like browser,...)
- switchback to Excel
- when our form hides the previously selected program becomes activated and is shown on top of Excel

Any solution to this issue? I have read two similar problems [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e83c7cd-2510-41fe-aef3-d34234d0058a/lost-focus-issue-when-using-windowinterophelper?forum=wpf) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a51ac7b9-7021-4669-accd-af0e86b9cc01/owner-window-lost-focus?forum=wpf), but they don't offer a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

(I realise this is an old question but hopefully will help someone in the future)

This seems to be a known bug with using window.Show() in wpf windows that hasn't been fixed ( [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e83c7cd-2510-41fe-aef3-d34234d0058a/lost-focus-issue-when-using-windowinterophelper?forum=wpf) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e83c7cd-2510-41fe-aef3-d34234d0058a/lost-focus-issue-when-using-windowinterophelper?forum=wpf) )

Forcing focus to the Owner before Closing seems to work for me (Solution posted in the first link):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// Getting the active window
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

// Using the WindowInteropHelper to bind WPF window to excel
var wpfWindow = new WPFWindow();
wpfWindow.Closing += (sender, args) => SetForegroundWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow).Owner);
var handle = GetActiveWindow();
helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow) { Owner = handle };
wpfWindow.Show();
```

Comment: if it can help others as I had a lot of issue with Excel for instance, this solution worked for me with only one difference, instead of using GetActiveWindow I used *Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle* as the Owner